# Compiling python script with a dependable python script using pyinstaller - QT related error

Tags: python, qt, pyinstaller

I need to make a python executable in ubuntu, of my code, which has got a python dependency of another python class.

```
dbscan.py
class dbscan:
#some code goes here

helloworld.py
import dbscan
from dbscan import *
#again some more code goes here
```

I am using pyinstaller to create the executable,

> pyinstaller helloworld.py

If I use the same for a python program which doesn't uses classes from other python files it runs just fine, but when i create executable with a case like above I get this error, when i run the executable

```
File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

Comment: make sure its using the same python (its on like the 10th line)

Comment: i don't quite get what you are asking for, i am using python 2.7 on my machine